# No such file or directory "\\seleniumwire\\ca.crt"

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've created a Python exe file. When I run it on the computer it was coded on it works. However when I run it on another PC I get this error.

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI180322\\seleniumwire\\ca.crt'
```

I think this is because when I was testing and coding another script a while ago I downloaded the certificate to see if that would help the browser. Now on this script it makes it fail.

How can I remove this so selenium/seleniumwire doesn't use `ca.crt`?

Comment: Which selenium are you using? Are they different in both of your computers?

Comment: @pvy4917 they're both the same I believe, I don't know which versions but I updated them both using pip. Although I'm running it as an .exe on the second PC so I shouldn't have to install python in anyway to use it.

Comment: @pvy4917 I go into a bit more detail https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire/issues/402

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from github if anyone else runs into problems.
[here](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire/issues/402)

> There's no need for users to install the key - users would only
> normally install ca.crt if they wished to get rid of the insecure icon
> displayed by the browser. However, Selenium Wire does need access to
> both the key and crt to perform request interception.
>
> The way it works normally is Selenium Wire loads ca.crt and ca.key
> from its library module, concatenates them to a single file called
> seleniumwire-ca.pem and stores that in /.seleniumwire. From that
> point on, Selenium Wire will just use seleniumwire-ca.pem directly. It
> will only try and load ca.crt and ca.key again if seleniumwire-ca.pem
> disappears (e.g. is deleted).
>
> It still feels like we need to crack the issue with PyInstaller not
> properly providing ca.crt and ca.key as this will resolve the issue
> properly. I'll try and do that as soon as I have some proper time.
>
> One final thing to mention is that you can control the location of the
> .seleniumwire folder with the request_storage_base_dir option. That
> defaults to the system TEMP folder, but if you wanted to change that
> you can control it using that option.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire/issues/402#issuecomment-1059038086

to get the ca.crt, enter the following command: python -m seleniumwire extractcert ./ca.crt

here is the ca.key: https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire/blob/master/seleniumwire/ca.key